# Formatted string parsing

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm calling a web service that returns the following string:

```
anyType{x=4;y=5;z=acq}
```

How do you get the values of `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: What web service are you trying to pull from?

Comment: The web service supposed to return xml, but i got this. So i just ask while i' m trying to find a solution(SOAP WS)

Comment: Is it always in the format of `anyType{x=%s;y=%s;z=%s}`?

Comment: yes always in the same format

Comment: There should be a clean way to parse that XML itself. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Let us know what you've tried and we'll make suggestions... Here's a hint: Check out the method named `indexOf` on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: you made a SOAP call to a web service and _this_ is the response you got?  seems like a bug...

Comment: Ok well i think i 'll try this: String[] tokens = response.split(";");         for (String t : tokens)
               System.out.println(t);

Comment: Yes this is the response of the ws. And that is the reason i asked the question. It's awkward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the web service, the problem is with the KSOAP2 android library that i' m using.
the code i used to get the result was:

```
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
ht.debug = true;
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
String response = envelope.getResponse().toString();
```

I had to use the following line to get the response as xml:

```
String responseXML = ht.responseDump;
```

So now there is no problem with parsing the xml response.
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an optimal solution, but works for debugging info.

However, it is, like others suggested preferable to get the result as XML (or JSON), as you can use a robust library for parsing the data.

```
final Matcher matcher =
        Pattern.compile("\\w+\\{x=(\\w+);y=(\\w+);z=(\\w+)\\}")
               .matcher("anyType{x=4;y=5;z=acq}");

while (matcher.find()) {
    final String x = matcher.group(1);
    final String y = matcher.group(2);
    final String z = matcher.group(3);
}
```